# Laravel dynamic email not sending by Mailable Class

Tags: laravel, sendgrid, laravel-mail

In my case, In the Mailable Class I store the email in the variable hardcode form LIKE

```php
$email = 'abc@example.com';
```

then, its work fine. but when we pass the email dynamically from the Controller LIKE

```php
$this->email;
```

this shows the error are given below :

> Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements "

```php
$subject = 'Account Created Successfully';

$name = 'Saakin Qatar';

return $this->view('emails.AgencyRegisterMail')

                   ->from($address, $name)

                   ->cc($address, $name)

                   ->bcc($address, $name)

                   ->replyTo($address, $name)

                   ->subject($subject)

                   ->with('inputs', $this->inputs);
```

It works but when I pass the address from the controller and store it like below:

```php
$subject = 'Account Created Successfully';

$name = 'Saakin Qatar';

$name = 'Saakin Qatar';

return $this->view('emails.AgencyRegisterMail')

                    ->from($address, $name)

                    ->cc($address, $name)

                    ->bcc($address, $name)

                    ->replyTo($address, $name)

                    ->subject($subject)

                    ->with('inputs', $this->inputs);
```

then it returns the error

Comment: The two code blocks are equivalent. You should post the code that gives you the error.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

The error message here said:

> Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements

On [the page it recommends you visit](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/) it describes that to send emails you need to send them from either an [email address that has been verified](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) or an [email address from an authenticated domain](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication).

My guess is that you are building a contact form of sorts and trying to send the mail from an email address that a user enters into the form. If that is the case, you cannot use the user provided email address as the `from` parameter for sending the email, you have to use an email address that is verified or authenticated. But you can set the user's email address as the `replyTo` so that when you reply from your email client you write back to the user.